# Trying to pass XML variable to function to update XML file

Tags: powershell

Hi guys (and maybe gals),

In Powershell i'm trying to pass a variable to my function, which I want to use to update a specific node in my XML file. I want to pass the variable $xml.config.server.username (the node in my XML file) to my function and use that to check if it's filled and if it's not filled, fill it with the $Value also passed to the function.

So far I tried this:

```
function XMLChecker
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $XMLFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Value,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $LocationinXML
)

{
$XML = New-Object XML
$XML.load($XMLFile)

if ($LocationinXML -eq "") {
        Write-host "Value $Value is not found in XML file, adding it in the file." -fore Yellow
        $LocationinXML = [string]$Value
        $XML.save("$XMLFile")
        $XML.load("$XMLFile")
    }
```

And to call the function, I tried this:

```
XMLChecker -XMLFile C:\config.xml -Value "jabadabadoo" -LocationinXML "$xml.config.server.username" -ErrorAction Stop
```

Here is a part of my test XML file:

```
<config version="1.0">
  <server dnsname="localhost" ip="127.0.0.1" username="share" />
</config>
```

I'm guessing it is something small which I overlooked (so easy points for you guys :)).

Comment: `if($LocationinXML -eq "")` is oxymoronic. It's not going to work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a scriptblock-parameter or `Invoke-Expression` + string-parameter to achieve this. I would avoid requiring `$xml` in the parameter-value because users shouldn't have to know how the function is built.

Invoke-Expression:

```
function XMLChecker {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $XMLFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Value,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $LocationinXML
    )

    $XML = New-Object XML
    $XML.load($XMLFile)

    if ((Invoke-Expression "`$xml.$LocationinXML") -eq "") {
        Write-host "Value $Value is not found in XML file, adding it in the file." -fore Yellow
        Invoke-Expression "`$xml.$LocationinXML = '$Value'"
        $XML.save("$XMLFile")
    }

}

XMLChecker -XMLFile "C:\config.xml" -Value "jabadabadoo" -LocationinXML "config.server.usernames" -ErrorAction Stop
```

Scriptblock:

```
function XMLChecker {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $XMLFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Value,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [scriptblock]$LocationinXML
    )

    $XML = New-Object XML
    $XML.load($XMLFile)

    if (($LocationinXML.Invoke().Trim()) -eq "") {
        Write-host "Value $Value is not found in XML file, adding it in the file." -fore Yellow
        [scriptblock]::Create("$LocationinXML = '$Value'").Invoke()        
        $XML.save("$XMLFile")
    }

}

XMLChecker -XMLFile "C:\config.xml" -Value "jabadabadoo" -LocationinXML { $xml.config.server.username } -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Working as a charm. Thanks for your reponse and the options!